# find background image location in url content

Tags: java

i want to save the background image of "http://yooz.ir/" to my Disk by a java code. this image changes every few days. it has a download link [blue arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN0mq.jpg), but i don't find image location to save it by code. how i can find the location of this image in url content by jsoup, htmlunit or etc?

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong url. Here is the right one: http://imgs.yooz.ir/yooz/walls/yooz-950602-2.jpg

Comment: very thank you for your answer. but how i can find the right url by my java code? the background image of yooz.ir changes every few days. the "http://imgs.yooz.ir/yooz/walls/" is fixed, but how i can find the name of image of day by my java code? thanks

Comment: @mhm you'll need to get the source of the page and then parse it. See the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see this element is populated **asynchronously** 
 so you need to use some webdriver automation tool, the most common is selenium

```
/*
import selenium, you can do it via maven;
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.45.0</version>
</dependency>
 */
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SaveImageFromUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // download chrome driver http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
        // or use firefox, w/e u like
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverLocation);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // opens browsers
        driver.get("http://yooz.ir/"); // redirect to site
        // wait until element which contains the download link exist in page
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.findElement(By.className("image-day__download"));
            }
        });

        // get the link inside the element via queryselector
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
        String img2download = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".image-day__download a")).getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println("img2download = " + img2download);

        //TODO download..

        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but where i can add above codes in my code? i add jsoup library and copy "Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://yooz.ir/"); ... " in main method and " cannot resolve symbol 'input' " appears? i add "import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor; ... " in new class Tutorials and "cannot resolve symbol 'openga' " apears?

Comment: thank you jim. i can not run your code: i cannot download chrome driver, so i change "System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverLocation);" to comment and change "WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();" to "WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();". but when i run the code, "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/47.0.1/firstrun/learnmore/" appears not "yooz.ir" and after seconds many errors appear. i am working with firefox and i donot want to open the browser; i want to find background image link remotely. i try by Jsoup, but i cannot. i am beginner in java.

Comment: You will beed to open a browser, web driver, you can run it "headless", edit ur main question with errors, learn about queryselector in html and ajax and u will understand the rest